# Jquery Compare table rows selected with checkbox and compare a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatables

i have a table that i compare row values using checkbox to see if they are the same, am using a jquery code to compare the table rows that were selected by a checkbox, it works perfectly, now what i want is to be able to exclude two columns from the comparison and compare other columns in the two selected rows

```js
$('.ApprovalForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser
    if ($(":checkbox:checked").length < 2 || $(":checkbox:checked").length > 2) {
        alert('You have to select two flights');
    } else {
        var form = $(this);
        //get all checkboxes that are selected
        var selected = $("input:checked");

        //loop through your columns
        var x = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
            var prev = null;
            $.each($(selected), function() {
                var curr = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(i).text();
                //if at least one value is different highlight the column
                if (curr !== prev && prev !== null) {
                    x++;
                    console.log(3333);
                }
                prev = curr;

            })
        }

        console.log(x);
        if (x <= 0) {
            $("#modal-Approve").modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
            }).done(function(response) {
                $("#MessageStatus ").val(response);
                location.reload();

            }).fail(function(data) {
                // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                alert(data);
            });
        } else {
            alert('Selected flights are not the same, check if they are the same by using detail  button');
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="display:none">id</th>
   <th>Mission</th>
   <th>First Pilot</th>
   <th>Second Pilot</th>
   <th>Aircraft</th>
   <th>No</th>

   <th style="display:none">TakeOffTime</th>
   <th style="display:none">LandingTime</th>
   <th style="display:none">Date</th>

  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>    
   <td>test Flying</td>
   <td>Juliet</td>
   <td>Pascal</td>
   <td>boeing 42</td>
   <td>255</td>
   <td>12:45</td>
   <td>14:20</td> <!-- exclude this from the values that will  be compared -->
   <td>12/1/2020</td> <!-- exclude this too -->
   <td> <input type="checkbox" name="FlightId[]"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>    
   <td>test Flying</td>
   <td>Juliet</td>
   <td>Pascal</td>
   <td>boeing 42</td>
   <td>255</td>
   <td>12:45</td>
   <td>14:30</td> <!-- exclude this from the values that will  be compared -->
   <td>12/2/2020</td> <!-- exclude this too -->
   <td> <input type="checkbox" name="FlightId[]"> </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

so the idea is to be able to exclude some td values from the comparison

Answer (score 0):

- Add 'exc_toggle' class to each **th** in your header row
- Add event listener for clicking these classes to toggle an 'exclude' data attribute
- Add a hidden cell to each row in **tbody** so your column counts are the same between the header and **tbody** rows
- Add to your form submit event listener to iterate over the 'exc_toggle' class and create a to_ignore index for each data-exclude = 1
- Skip your comparison when i is found in your ignore index

Code below.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr id="header_row">
            <th style="display:none" class="exc_toggle">id</th>
            <th class="exc_toggle">Mission</th>
            <th class="exc_toggle">First Pilot</th>
            <th class="exc_toggle">Second Pilot</th>
            <th class="exc_toggle">Aircraft</th>
            <th class="exc_toggle">No</th>

            <th class="exc_toggle">TakeOffTime</th>
            <th class="exc_toggle">LandingTime</th>
            <th class="exc_toggle">Date</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>    
            <td style="display:none"></td>
            <td>test Flying</td>
            <td>Juliet</td>
            <td>Pascal</td>
            <td>boeing 42</td>
            <td>255</td>
            <td>12:45</td>
            <td>14:20</td> <!-- exclude this from the values that will  be compared -->
            <td>12/1/2020</td> <!-- exclude this too -->
            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="FlightId[]"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td style="display:none"></td>
            <td>test Flying</td>
            <td>Juliet</td>
            <td>Pascal</td>
            <td>boeing 42</td>
            <td>255</td>
            <td>12:45</td>
            <td>14:30</td> <!-- exclude this from the values that will  be compared -->
            <td>12/2/2020</td> <!-- exclude this too -->
            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="FlightId[]"> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery (in document header):

```
        $(document).on('click', '.exc_toggle', function(){
            if($(this).data('exclude') == 1)
            {
                $(this).data('exclude', 0);
                $(this).css('background-color', '');
            } else {
                $(this).data('exclude', 1);
                $(this).css('background-color', '#F00');
            }           
        });
```

jQuery (modified ApprovalForm submit event):

```
$('.ApprovalForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser
    if ($(":checkbox:checked").length < 2 || $(":checkbox:checked").length > 2) {
        alert('You have to select two flights');
    } else {
        var ignore_indices = [];
        var cnt = 0;
        $('.exc_toggle').each(function(){
            if($(this).data('exclude') == 1)
                {ignore_indices.push(cnt);}
            cnt++;
        });

        var form = $(this);
        //get all checkboxes that are selected
        var selected = $("input:checked");

        //loop through your columns
        var x = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
            if(ignore_indices.indexOf(i) < 0)
            {
                var prev = null;
                $.each($(selected), function() {
                    var curr = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(i).text();
                    //if at least one value is different highlight the column
                    if (curr !== prev && prev !== null) {
                        x++;
                        console.log(3333);
                    }
                    prev = curr;

                })
            } else {
                prev = null;
            }
        }

        console.log(x);
        if (x <= 0) {
            $("#modal-Approve").modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
            }).done(function(response) {
                $("#MessageStatus ").val(response);
                location.reload();

            }).fail(function(data) {
                // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                alert(data);
            });
        } else {
            alert('Selected flights are not the same, check if they are the same by using detail  button');
        }
    }
});
```

To compare duplicate takeoff times, add the class 'takeoff' to each td in your takeoff time column, then add this jQuery:

```
        $(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox', function(){
            var takeoff = '';
            $('.takeoff').css('background-color', '');
            $('input:checked').each(function(){
                var td_target = $(this).closest('tr').find('.takeoff');
                takeoff = td_target.html();

                var matches = $('input:checked').parents('tr').find('.takeoff:contains("'+takeoff+'")');
                if(matches.length > 1)
                    {td_target.css('background-color', '#F00');}
                else
                    {td_target.css('background-color', '');}
            });
        });
```

Comment: thanks for the code, it worked flawlessly, for anyone having this issue , go to the th that you need to be excluded and add  data-exclude="1" .

Comment: I have updated you, and SO said i t has recorded it but wont display it publicly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second comment. Was there an issue with the code?

Comment: Not at all, its because of am yet to reach the reputation point set by SO before my votes can be seen publicly

Comment: Please how can i highlight "TakeOffTime" column duplicate value  if check box is checked,

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, I have tested the code and it says reference error "$ is not defined" is not defined and also please what i wanted is  to check for on two columns, "TakeOffTime" and "Date" columns duplicates when the first checkbox is checked and highlight the detected duplicates, thanks. I think the current code you updated checks for "TakeOffTime" column only and it does that when all the checkboxes are checked